# Clip Square region from Point Geometry

Tags: google-earth-engine, planet

I have a series of (lat, lng) coordinates and I need to extract 10x10 sq_km satellite imagery from them.

Google Earth Engine (GEE) has this functionality:

```
geometry = ee.Geometry.Point(lat, lng).buffer(10000)
```

That clips the defined region but gives me a circular geometry, is there a way to extract a square geometry enclosing the circle.

I am also ok with replicating the same using Planet-API.

Also, what is a good way to download large number of such regions from GEE.

Comment: You have to ask one question at a time. I'll answer the first one and make another post for the second.

Comment: Sure, thanks. Shall I ask the second question again?

Comment: yes, edit this question leaving just one, and ask another with the second, and you should explain it a bit better, what you mean by "such regions"? what have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every `ee.Geometry` object has a method called `bounds`:

> **bounds(maxError, proj)**
>
> Returns the bounding rectangle of the geometry.
>
> Arguments: this:geometry (Geometry): Return the bounding box of this
>   geometry.
>
> maxError (ErrorMargin, default: null): The maximum amount of error
>   tolerated when performing any necessary reprojection.
>
> proj (Projection, default: null): If specified, the result will be in
>   this projection. Otherwise it will be in WGS84.
>
> Returns: Geometry

So,

```
geometry = ee.Geometry.Point(lat, lng).buffer(10000).bounds()
```